# Bash How to pass mysql, through ssh, to read

Tags: bash

I currently have a script that looks like this:

```
sql="SELECT id FROM user 
     WHERE (email LIKE '%a@b.com' 
            OR email LIKE '%c@d.com' 
            OR email LIKE '%f@g.com' );"

read -a ids < <(ssh localhost "mysql test -e \"$sql\"")
```

But it isn't executing properly. When using `set -x`, the output looks like this:

```
+ read -a usu_ids
++ ssh localhost 'mysql test -e " SELECT' id FROM user WHERE '(usu_email' LIKE ''\''%a@b.com'\''' OR email LIKE ''\''%c@d.com'\''' OR email LIKE ''\''%f@g.com'\''' '); "'
```

And it gives out a bogus value. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Option 1:`Here's an example, you can tweak this to suit your needs:

```
$ ssh user@hostname <<END
> cd temp_files
> ls -lrt
> #Run any commands on the remote host here
> END

total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 test test 4096 May 27 14:18 cron_log
```

`Option 2 :` You can put the commands to be run on remote hosts in a local script and run it using ssh. An example is given below :

```
$ cat SO.sh
cd ~/temp_files
ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}'
$
$ myVar=`ssh user@remotehost 'bash -s' < SO.sh`
$
$ echo ${myVar}
cron_log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the mysql DB name at the end of the mysql command:

```
read -a ids < <(ssh localhost "mysql -e \"$sql\" test")
```